# Очень долгая загрузка первоначальной страницы ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

Здравствуйте!

Есть проект:

- Платформа: ASP MVC (.NET 4.5) + DevExpress компоненты.
- Проблема: Запуск index страницы очень долгий. Как только страница загрузилась проект начинает работать в нормальном режиме, никаких подтормаживаний нет.

Как соптимизировать первоначальный запуск проекта?

Консоль выдает:

```
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
"iisexpress.exe" (CLR v4.0.30319: DefaultDomain). Загружено "C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.ApplicationServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.ApplicationServices.dll". Загрузка символов пропущена. Модуль оптимизирован, включен параметр отладчика "Только мой код".
....
```

Comment: ну кто ж знает, что у вас там внутри

Comment: Долго грузится только при первом запуске приложения на IIS или при каждом запуске в новой сессии браузера?

Comment: только при первом

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сам по себе старт ASP.NET приложения - довольно медленный процесс, особенно если у вас все еще используются aspx/ascx страницы/views или ресурсы в папках App_GlobalResources и App_LocalResources. Это вызвано тем, что ASP.NET при старте

- создает shadow copy почти всего из bin в своей папке Temporary ASP.NET Files.
- генерирует из aspx/ascx/cshtml и файлов ресурсов код и компилирует его.
- в процессе холодного запуска еще и компилирует IL для всей пачки полученных файлов в инструкции для конкретной системы.

Поэтому время старта приложения очень сильно проседает.

Для ускорения запуска на машине разработчика можно использовать:

- запуск не под отладчиком - он *оооооочень* замедляет старт. Запускайте по `Ctrl+F5`, и только когда вам нужен отладчик - цепляйтесь к процессу IIS/IIS Express через `Debug / Attach To Process`, `Ctrl+Alt+P`.
- флаг `<compilation optimizeCompilations="true">` в `web.config` - [тут подробно расписано что именно он делает](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davidebb/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior).
- побольше памяти и SSD в качестве системного диска.

Для ускорения запуска на живом сервере можно использовать:

- прогон утилитой [aspnet_compile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms229863%28v=vs.140%29).
- [App Suspend](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-app-suspend-responsive-shared-net-web-hosting/), если у вас проблемы со стартом приложения после остановки из-за неактивности (aka утренние тормоза).
- установку сборок DevExpress и всего остального редко меняющегося в GAC - тогда ASP.NET не будет копировать их Temp, что ускорит старт.
- прогон сборок DevExpress и всего остального редко меняющегося через [Native Image Generator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator).

На практике обычно хватает `aspnet_compile`. Время работы утилиты практически совпадает с задержкой при старте приложения, т.е. если она у вас работает 5 минут - то приложение стартует на 5 минут быстрее.